# Use fetch to return parsed Json

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I have the following code in my javascript:

```
 fetch(Url).then(r => r.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(e => "failed")
```

I am looking for a way to returned the JSON.parse(data) instead of just logging it to the console.  I am specifically looking to retrieve the Name value from the json returned

I have tried below with no success:

```
.then(data => obj = JSON.parse(data))
```

Any help to return just the obj.Name from the Json data returned would be appreciated.